# Use Xorg autoconfig to dynamically apply settings depending on monitor?

Tags: xorg, gentoo, xorg.conf, autoconf

The setup is as follows:

- a common Gentoo linux based system image (has to be shared between all)
- 1 out of 3 different touch based input devices
- 1 out of 3 different monitors

There is always only one monitor and touch-input, but the combination can be arbitrary. So far not challenging, but two of the three monitors use a 90° rotation while the third requires a 270° rotation. In my old setup this was "solved" by having different Xorg.conf files for *each combination*, detecting the combination at boot-up and creating a symlink to the correct configuration via a script that was run to bring up X.

"InputClass" wildcards work very well to detect and configure the touch-input regardless which one is present; however I'm not faring that well with the monitor (I couldn't find anything like a "MonitorClass" for dynamic matching and I really don't want to have to use a pre-run script again..)

Is it possible to (ab)use the autoconfig features of Xorg to apply the rotation and build a dynamic setup based on the monitor that X detects?

Comment: Maybe use `xrandr` in runtime, e.g. xsession scriptlets?

Comment: Yeah that's what I ended up doing